# The normal formal of integer matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, modules

We know that a complex matrix is conjugeted to the Jordan form, and for a real matrix we have a similar result. Now I want to know the situation for the integer matrix. More precisely, for a matrix $T\in GL(d,\mathbb{Z})$, does there exist a normal form $N\in GL(d,\mathbb{Z})$ and a matrix $P\in GL(d,\mathbb{Z})$ such that
$$
N=PTP^{-1}.
$$ 
Thanks in advance.